# Scaling in Node.js with MongoDB, when should I query all IDs at once, vs querying each in parallel?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, scaling, async.js

Lets say I have a script thats processes N users. The script could look one of two ways, which is faster assuming ample resources? I could use either `Promise.all` or `async.parallel`.

Option 1

```
function processUsers(userIds) {
    monog.find({_id: { $in: userIds }, (userDocs) => {
        const tasks = userDocs.map((userDoc) => processUser(userDoc))
        async.parallel(tasks, (err, results) => console.log('finished'))
    });
}
```

Option 2

```
function processUsers(userIds) {
    const tasks = userIds.map((userId) => {
        mongo.findOne({_id: userId}, (err, userDoc) => {
            processUser(userDoc);
        })
    })
    async.parallel(tasks, (err, results) => console.log('finished'))
}
```

Comment: In option 2, you're doing a whole bunch more db requests, which will take a lot longer than a single query.  Is this a trick question? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to read all in once or at least read them in big chunks. Definitely don't read them one by one, that will be a lot of unnecessary db traffic. Read all at once, if you think you have enough memory for it.

Also, random thought but if `processUser` involves DB writes, you could collect results and use [bulkWrite](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite) to speed up things even more.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 seems like a better choice IMO. `find()` performs better than `findOne()` since when using `find()` you get back a cursor and not the actual data from the database. Traversing this cursor will give better results than retrieving each document individually using `findOne()`.

Answer (score 0):

i would say it depends.

The two operations in question: query(find/findOne), and data processing (processUser()) - depending on which one takes more work in the actual virtual machine, you may want to make them leverage the asynchronous behavior of Node.js. For example, if the find() is in orders of millisesonss where the processing is in the order of seconds, you would want to make the process asynchronous, as you don't want to sequence them up to add the overall time.

While in general the db query is I/O bound and is more time consuming than memory bound operations, we have to actually see the specificity of the workload, and take a call accordingly.

Hope this helps.